# Select single column by detecting col-name and keep colname

Tags: r

I have a data.frame (df1) in which I want to transfer one (or more) certain columns to a new data frame (df2). When I with

```
which(str_detect (colnames (data), col-key))
```

search for the columns, and match several columns, then the column names are retained. If I only match one column in df1, the column name is not kept. Why is that?

Examplary:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "b"), col2 = c(1, 2))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c("123456789", "123456780"))
```

select multiple cols by str_detect: ✓

```
df2 <- df2 %>% bind_cols(df1[, str_detect(colnames(df1), "col")])

id col1 col2
1 123456789    a    1
2 123456780    b    2
```

select single col by str_detect: ❌

```
df2 <- df2 %>% bind_cols(df1[, str_detect(colnames(df1), "col1")])

New names:
* NA -> ...2
> 
> df2
         id ...2
1 123456789    a
2 123456780    b
```

What is the reason for this that the column name is not adopted?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the problem and it can be solved easily. When selecting a single column, drop = FALSE must be specified, otherwise the structure will not be retained.

```
df2 <- df2 %>% bind_cols(df1[, str_detect(colnames(df1), "col1"), drop = FALSE])
id col1
1 123456789    a
2 123456780    b
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the fact that when selecting just one column, it doesn't retain the data frame structure (do `df1[, str_detect(colnames(df1), "col1")]` to see what I mean).
To solve this, you could respecify the column name when doing bind_cols():

```
df2 %>% bind_cols("col1" = df1[, str_detect(colnames(df1), "col1")])
```

Gives:
id     |  col1
123456789  |  a
123456780   | b